# Is applyUpdates() really needed in hook_install()?

Tags: hooks, installation, 8

I maintain a contributed module which defines two base fields, but these are not added to any content type on installation, as this is done from administrator users. The module uses the following line in in `hook_install()` and `hook_uninstall()`.

```php
// Add our base fields to the schema.
\Drupal::service('entity.definition_update_manager')->applyUpdates();
```

Now that this function is deprecated in Drupal 8.7, as described in [Support for automatic entity updates has been removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742), I've tried removing the lines and installing, and it seems to work OK.

Is removing the calls to `applyUpdates()` OK?

I think there were problems with fields not being deleted in the early days of Drupal 8, but maybe that works better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change record you've linked is about update hooks for already installed modules, not hook_install().

You've never needed `applyUpdates()` in an install hook. If your custom module is adding a new field, it will be added automatically when the module is enabled, and removed when the module is uninstalled. There was only an issue with base fields containing data, but this is resolved since Drupal 8.5. See this change record: [Base fields with existing data can now be uninstalled](https://www.drupal.org/node/2907785).

Comment: Thanks 4k4 I was hoping that this was the case. I suspect that when we first starting converting from 7.x to 8.x there were some problems with the fields. But yes I agree that the change record only talks about `hook_update`. But that was the page given in the deprecation error message so I was working from that. There is also the open core issue https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2924256 which does affect fields left over after uninstall.

Comment: OK, then you could add a warning that fields added to a content type should be removed by the admin before uninstalling the module.